# Extending Existing HTML Tag Using Classes, Custom Tag, other method?

Tags: html, css

Edit: Yes I know that what I'm trying to do is convoluted and unnecessary. I assumed that I was missing some fundamental or basic HTML thing that could help me accomplish this, I just don't know enough about HTML/CSS to know what I'm looking for.

I'm relatively new to using HTML (I come from a quantitative background, where I almost exclusively used R and Python). I've probably said one or more things that are nonsensical or wildly incorrect, so please bear with me (and please point out anything I've misstated or gotten completely wrong so I can better my understanding!)

I like using the `<details>` tag. I've also found it useful for making little footnotes. However, I'd rather not have to specify the particular style characteristics every time I use it for footnotes, and I don't want to specify those characteristics by default using `<style>` since I do use `<details>` in other ways, too.

So I thought to make a custom HTML tag that is basically just `<details>`, but with the particular characteristics I want specifically for footnote-style usage. Ideally (for now), I'd like to do this within an HTML file itself rather than in a separate DOM. I've read a bunch of links on creating custom tags/elements, but I'm missing something to finish it. All of them seem to say that you can declare a new element within an HTML file as follows:

```
<x-foo></x-foo>
```

But what goes in between the tags to declare/define x-foo?

My goal is to declare a custom `<details-foot></details-foot>` corresponding with the following style sheet:

```
<style> 
    details {
        margin-bottom: 5px
    }

    details > summary {
      padding-top: 0px;
      padding-bottom: 0px;
      margin-top: 0px;
      margin-bottom: 0px;
      margin-left: 20px;
      font-size: 6pt
    }
    
    details > p {
      padding-top: 0px;
      padding-bottom: 0px;
      margin-top: 0px;
      margin-left: 20px;
      margin-bottom: 0px;
      font-size: 6pt
    }
</style>
```

I think I'm just barely missing the piece that I'm looking for, and my HTML knowledge is so limited that I don't know quite what that piece is. I appreciate your patience and help!

Cheers,
Matt

Comment: There is no sense in you create a new tag for HTML. You can select styles by attributes like classes or ids. There are a lot or infinite modes to do this. Please get more focus on learning about css and html, there is plenty documentation. Of course you can do this, but if you don't improve it, don't reinvent: your way is complex and a waste of time, is more quick and easy learn

Comment: Right, so what I was looking for was something like classes or ids. I figured my method was convoluted, but I'm also inexperienced enough with HTML/CSS to have known what was the basic thing that I was missing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set a custom class to use for specific types of formatting within the same document.

[More information here](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_classes.asp)

Essentially, you would have it so you have

```
<details class="foobar">
<summary></summary></details>
```

And in your header `<style>` tags (or ideally, in a separate css file), you would have:

```
.foobar {
[your styling here]
}
```

This would create a new type of details style.

Comment: This helped a bunch, thank you! I figured I wasn't considering some other basic HTML component that'd be helpful, and Class was it!

Comment: Glad it helped!